# SSIS - Splitting String into multiple rows

Tags: c#, ssis

Looking for some advice really. I've got a dataset for school attendance data that comes into me as: student_id, school_id, term_start_date, attendance_marks.

An example line of this data would be:

```
1234, 1002, 2016-09-01, '/\##/L/\##BB/\/\/\/\/\'
```

The attendance marks string is basically two sessions per day, each mark corresponds to various different codes. Basically, I get a start date and then have to work out each day's attendance mark going forward from that... horrible I know, but that's how I get the data I'm afraid.

I've written a script object to loop through this string and output a row for each day to get loaded into a data warehouse.

I should say before posting the code that this script works, it does what I need it to do... but it is painfully slow. I'm hoping I can draw upon the collective experience here to see if there is a more efficient way of achieving this?

```
public override void Input0_ProcessInputRow(Input0Buffer Row)
{
    int studentID = Row.STUDDENTID;
    int baseID = Row.SCHOOLID;
    DateTime dateKey = Row.STARTDATE;
    string marks = Row.MARKS.ToString();

    // TODO
    // This is a bodge at the moment to make sure the mark string is always divisible by 2
    // in the production release I'll have to handle this as an exception
    if (marks.Length % 2 != 0)
    {
        marks = marks + '@';
    }

    char[] c = marks.ToCharArray();

    for (int i = 0; i < c.Length; i += 2)
    {
        Output0Buffer.AddRow();
        Output0Buffer.baseID = baseID;
        Output0Buffer.studentID = studentID;
        Output0Buffer.dateKey = dateKey.AddDays(i / 2).Year * 10000 + dateKey.AddDays(i / 2).Month * 100 + dateKey.AddDays(i / 2).Day;
        Output0Buffer.markAM = c[i].ToString();
        Output0Buffer.markPM = c[i + 1].ToString();

        if (i == c.Length - 1)
        {
            base.FinishOutputs();
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a better way of doing this? Have I massively overthought it or do I just have to live with it taking ages to run? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What version of SQL are you using?

Comment: The Attendance data is read from an Oracle 12c database, using SSIS 2012 to load into an SQL 2012 database. The SQL Server side of things is only running on that currently because that is a spare server for me to test/prototype this on. Going forward I can install it on any version of SQL Server (I'd hope the latest one).

Comment: Is your staging area SQL Server 2012 then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could probably be written in Oracle Pl-SQL, though I neither work with Oracle nor recommend you doing transformations within your live system as part of the extract

---

If you load your data as is into a SQL Server staging environment, you can then return it in your `OLEDB Source` component using the script that utilises a derived tally table to split out the `Attendance` string into one character per row.  This will work with multiple students, schools and days (ie: it is a proper set based solution), so can be used as a one pass fetch that will return your entire dataset:

```
-- Create test data
declare @d table(StudentID int,SchoolID int, AttDate date, Attendance nvarchar(500));
insert into @d values
 (1234, 1002, '20160901', '/\##/L/\##BB/\/\/\/\')
,(1235, 1002, '20160901', '/\##/L/\##/\BB/\/\/\')
,(1234, 1002, '20160902', '/\##/L/\##BB/\/\/\/\/\')
,(1235, 1002, '20160902', '/\##/L/\/\BB/\/\##/\/\');

              -- Create a list of 10 rows
with n(n) as (select n from (values(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) n(n))
              -- Cross join 6 times to reach 1,000,000 numbers if required.  Filtered to longest Attendance string in the SELECT TOP()
    ,t(t) as (select top (select max(len(Attendance)) from @d) row_number() over (order by (select null)) from n n1,n n2,n n3,n n4,n n5,n n6)
select d.StudentID
        ,d.SchoolID
        ,d.AttDate
        ,d.Attendance
        ,t.t as AttCharNum
        ,substring(d.Attendance,t.t,1) as AttChar  -- Use SUBSTRING to retreive just the one character
from @d d
    join t  -- Join to numbers only where they are actually required
        on t.t <= len(d.Attendance)
order by d.StudentID
        ,d.AttDate
        ,t.t;
```

Output:

```
+-----------+----------+------------+------------------------+------------+---------+
| StudentID | SchoolID |  AttDate   |       Attendance       | AttCharNum | AttChar |
+-----------+----------+------------+------------------------+------------+---------+
|      1234 |     1002 | 2016-09-01 | /\##/L/\##BB/\/\/\/\   |          1 | /       |
|      1234 |     1002 | 2016-09-01 | /\##/L/\##BB/\/\/\/\   |          2 | \       |
|      1234 |     1002 | 2016-09-01 | /\##/L/\##BB/\/\/\/\   |          3 | #       |
|      1234 |     1002 | 2016-09-01 | /\##/L/\##BB/\/\/\/\   |          4 | #       |
|      1234 |     1002 | 2016-09-01 | /\##/L/\##BB/\/\/\/\   |          5 | /       |
|      1234 |     1002 | 2016-09-01 | /\##/L/\##BB/\/\/\/\   |          6 | L       |
|      1234 |     1002 | 2016-09-01 | /\##/L/\##BB/\/\/\/\   |          7 | /       |
|      1234 |     1002 | 2016-09-01 | /\##/L/\##BB/\/\/\/\   |          8 | \       |
|      1234 |     1002 | 2016-09-01 | /\##/L/\##BB/\/\/\/\   |          9 | #       |
|      1234 |     1002 | 2016-09-01 | /\##/L/\##BB/\/\/\/\   |         10 | #       |
|      1234 |     1002 | 2016-09-01 | /\##/L/\##BB/\/\/\/\   |         11 | B       |
|      1234 |     1002 | 2016-09-01 | /\##/L/\##BB/\/\/\/\   |         12 | B       |
|      1234 |     1002 | 2016-09-01 | /\##/L/\##BB/\/\/\/\   |         13 | /       |
|      1234 |     1002 | 2016-09-01 | /\##/L/\##BB/\/\/\/\   |         14 | \       |
|      1234 |     1002 | 2016-09-01 | /\##/L/\##BB/\/\/\/\   |         15 | /       |
|      1234 |     1002 | 2016-09-01 | /\##/L/\##BB/\/\/\/\   |         16 | \       |
|      1234 |     1002 | 2016-09-01 | /\##/L/\##BB/\/\/\/\   |         17 | /       |
|      1234 |     1002 | 2016-09-01 | /\##/L/\##BB/\/\/\/\   |         18 | \       |
|      1234 |     1002 | 2016-09-01 | /\##/L/\##BB/\/\/\/\   |         19 | /       |
|      1234 |     1002 | 2016-09-01 | /\##/L/\##BB/\/\/\/\   |         20 | \       |
|      1234 |     1002 | 2016-09-02 | /\##/L/\##BB/\/\/\/\/\ |          1 | /       |
|      1234 |     1002 | 2016-09-02 | /\##/L/\##BB/\/\/\/\/\ |          2 | \       |
|      1234 |     1002 | 2016-09-02 | /\##/L/\##BB/\/\/\/\/\ |          3 | #       |
|      1234 |     1002 | 2016-09-02 | /\##/L/\##BB/\/\/\/\/\ |          4 | #       |
|      1234 |     1002 | 2016-09-02 | /\##/L/\##BB/\/\/\/\/\ |          5 | /       |
|      1234 |     1002 | 2016-09-02 | /\##/L/\##BB/\/\/\/\/\ |          6 | L       |
|      1234 |     1002 | 2016-09-02 | /\##/L/\##BB/\/\/\/\/\ |          7 | /       |
|      1234 |     1002 | 2016-09-02 | /\##/L/\##BB/\/\/\/\/\ |          8 | \       |
|      1234 |     1002 | 2016-09-02 | /\##/L/\##BB/\/\/\/\/\ |          9 | #       |
|      1234 |     1002 | 2016-09-02 | /\##/L/\##BB/\/\/\/\/\ |         10 | #       |
|      1234 |     1002 | 2016-09-02 | /\##/L/\##BB/\/\/\/\/\ |         11 | B       |
|      1234 |     1002 | 2016-09-02 | /\##/L/\##BB/\/\/\/\/\ |         12 | B       |
|      1234 |     1002 | 2016-09-02 | /\##/L/\##BB/\/\/\/\/\ |         13 | /       |
|      1234 |     1002 | 2016-09-02 | /\##/L/\##BB/\/\/\/\/\ |         14 | \       |
|      1234 |     1002 | 2016-09-02 | /\##/L/\##BB/\/\/\/\/\ |         15 | /       |
|      1234 |     1002 | 2016-09-02 | /\##/L/\##BB/\/\/\/\/\ |         16 | \       |
|      1234 |     1002 | 2016-09-02 | /\##/L/\##BB/\/\/\/\/\ |         17 | /       |
|      1234 |     1002 | 2016-09-02 | /\##/L/\##BB/\/\/\/\/\ |         18 | \       |
|      1234 |     1002 | 2016-09-02 | /\##/L/\##BB/\/\/\/\/\ |         19 | /       |
|      1234 |     1002 | 2016-09-02 | /\##/L/\##BB/\/\/\/\/\ |         20 | \       |
|      1234 |     1002 | 2016-09-02 | /\##/L/\##BB/\/\/\/\/\ |         21 | /       |
|      1234 |     1002 | 2016-09-02 | /\##/L/\##BB/\/\/\/\/\ |         22 | \       |
|      1235 |     1002 | 2016-09-01 | /\##/L/\##/\BB/\/\/\   |          1 | /       |
|      1235 |     1002 | 2016-09-01 | /\##/L/\##/\BB/\/\/\   |          2 | \       |
|      1235 |     1002 | 2016-09-01 | /\##/L/\##/\BB/\/\/\   |          3 | #       |
|      1235 |     1002 | 2016-09-01 | /\##/L/\##/\BB/\/\/\   |          4 | #       |
|      1235 |     1002 | 2016-09-01 | /\##/L/\##/\BB/\/\/\   |          5 | /       |
|      1235 |     1002 | 2016-09-01 | /\##/L/\##/\BB/\/\/\   |          6 | L       |
|      1235 |     1002 | 2016-09-01 | /\##/L/\##/\BB/\/\/\   |          7 | /       |
|      1235 |     1002 | 2016-09-01 | /\##/L/\##/\BB/\/\/\   |          8 | \       |
|      1235 |     1002 | 2016-09-01 | /\##/L/\##/\BB/\/\/\   |          9 | #       |
|      1235 |     1002 | 2016-09-01 | /\##/L/\##/\BB/\/\/\   |         10 | #       |
|      1235 |     1002 | 2016-09-01 | /\##/L/\##/\BB/\/\/\   |         11 | /       |
|      1235 |     1002 | 2016-09-01 | /\##/L/\##/\BB/\/\/\   |         12 | \       |
|      1235 |     1002 | 2016-09-01 | /\##/L/\##/\BB/\/\/\   |         13 | B       |
|      1235 |     1002 | 2016-09-01 | /\##/L/\##/\BB/\/\/\   |         14 | B       |
|      1235 |     1002 | 2016-09-01 | /\##/L/\##/\BB/\/\/\   |         15 | /       |
|      1235 |     1002 | 2016-09-01 | /\##/L/\##/\BB/\/\/\   |         16 | \       |
|      1235 |     1002 | 2016-09-01 | /\##/L/\##/\BB/\/\/\   |         17 | /       |
|      1235 |     1002 | 2016-09-01 | /\##/L/\##/\BB/\/\/\   |         18 | \       |
|      1235 |     1002 | 2016-09-01 | /\##/L/\##/\BB/\/\/\   |         19 | /       |
|      1235 |     1002 | 2016-09-01 | /\##/L/\##/\BB/\/\/\   |         20 | \       |
|      1235 |     1002 | 2016-09-02 | /\##/L/\/\BB/\/\##/\/\ |          1 | /       |
|      1235 |     1002 | 2016-09-02 | /\##/L/\/\BB/\/\##/\/\ |          2 | \       |
|      1235 |     1002 | 2016-09-02 | /\##/L/\/\BB/\/\##/\/\ |          3 | #       |
|      1235 |     1002 | 2016-09-02 | /\##/L/\/\BB/\/\##/\/\ |          4 | #       |
|      1235 |     1002 | 2016-09-02 | /\##/L/\/\BB/\/\##/\/\ |          5 | /       |
|      1235 |     1002 | 2016-09-02 | /\##/L/\/\BB/\/\##/\/\ |          6 | L       |
|      1235 |     1002 | 2016-09-02 | /\##/L/\/\BB/\/\##/\/\ |          7 | /       |
|      1235 |     1002 | 2016-09-02 | /\##/L/\/\BB/\/\##/\/\ |          8 | \       |
|      1235 |     1002 | 2016-09-02 | /\##/L/\/\BB/\/\##/\/\ |          9 | /       |
|      1235 |     1002 | 2016-09-02 | /\##/L/\/\BB/\/\##/\/\ |         10 | \       |
|      1235 |     1002 | 2016-09-02 | /\##/L/\/\BB/\/\##/\/\ |         11 | B       |
|      1235 |     1002 | 2016-09-02 | /\##/L/\/\BB/\/\##/\/\ |         12 | B       |
|      1235 |     1002 | 2016-09-02 | /\##/L/\/\BB/\/\##/\/\ |         13 | /       |
|      1235 |     1002 | 2016-09-02 | /\##/L/\/\BB/\/\##/\/\ |         14 | \       |
|      1235 |     1002 | 2016-09-02 | /\##/L/\/\BB/\/\##/\/\ |         15 | /       |
|      1235 |     1002 | 2016-09-02 | /\##/L/\/\BB/\/\##/\/\ |         16 | \       |
|      1235 |     1002 | 2016-09-02 | /\##/L/\/\BB/\/\##/\/\ |         17 | #       |
|      1235 |     1002 | 2016-09-02 | /\##/L/\/\BB/\/\##/\/\ |         18 | #       |
|      1235 |     1002 | 2016-09-02 | /\##/L/\/\BB/\/\##/\/\ |         19 | /       |
|      1235 |     1002 | 2016-09-02 | /\##/L/\/\BB/\/\##/\/\ |         20 | \       |
|      1235 |     1002 | 2016-09-02 | /\##/L/\/\BB/\/\##/\/\ |         21 | /       |
|      1235 |     1002 | 2016-09-02 | /\##/L/\/\BB/\/\##/\/\ |         22 | \       |
+-----------+----------+------------+------------------------+------------+---------+
```

Comment: Awesome, I'll have a play and see what I can get working. I suspect this is a far better way of doing it and it will be the last time I listen to a C# developer about loading data :)

Comment: @JayP  No worries, glad you got thing sorted :)